# Combine jQuery Globalize with underscore.js template?

Tags: javascript, templates, underscore.js, jquery-globalization

I'm using an underscore template to create an HTML list, this list contains a date field that I would like to globalize. A simplification of the template looks like this:

```
<li>Date: <%= date %> </li>
```

This date is a Javascript date object, so don't want to print the value directly, I would like to print it using globalize. Without the template the solution should look like this:

```js
var html = "<li>Date: " + Globalize.format(settings.get('lastUpdate'),'F') + "</li>";
```

Do you think I can use the template to achieve this or I must use a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call any globally accessible function inside your template. So, if `Globalize` is global (i.e. a property of `window`), then this template:

```
<script id="tmpl" type="text/html">
    <li>Date: <%= Globalize.format(date, 'F') %></li>
</script>
```

will work with this JavaScript:

```
_.template($('#tmpl').html(), {
    date: some_date_that_globalize_understands
});
```

If you don't have `Globalize` globally available then you could:

```
window.Globalize = Globalize;
```

to make it globally available or just add it to the template's namespace manually:

```
_.template($('#tmpl').html(), {
    Globalize: Globalize,
    date:      some_date_that_globalize_understands
});
```

Demos:

1. [Global `Globalize` through `window.Globalize`.](http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/7ta9d/).
2. [Local `Globalize` through the `_.template` parameters.](http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/8XkT8/).

There's really nothing special about the Underscore templates, the stuff inside `<%= %>` is just JavaScript code that ends up wrapped in a [`with` block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with). You can even see the function's source by looking at the `source` property on the returned template function:

```
var t = _.template($('#t').html());
console.log(t.source);
```

and you'll see some fairly simple (if ugly) JavaScript like this:

```
function(obj){
var __p='';var print=function(){__p+=Array.prototype.join.call(arguments, '')};
with(obj||{}){
__p+='\n    '+
( Globalize.mangle(pancakes) )+
'\n';
}
return __p;
}
```

That `+ (Globalize.mangle(pancakes) )+` bit is what `<%= Globalize.mangle(pancakes) %>` gets turned into. No magic, no special parsing of the contents of `<%= ... %>`, just a simpleminded (but effective) conversion to JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and correct answer and sorry for my late comment. I thought I could only place variables between <%= %>, but call the Globalize functions works perfect.